# Do HTTP requests get lost?

Tags: http, web-development-server

I'm developing my first app. When I send a request from my app to the local server it is always sucessful. What's it like in real life? How many requests out of 1000 would get lost in production?

Comment: Impossible to say - but your app definitely has to be able to deal with connection outages. There's a million reasons why one could occur anywhere between your device and the server.

Comment: It depends on the system architecture. You can design everything so that no requests will ever get lost, but it won't happen by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as something leaves your realm, you lose control. So, yes, HTTP requests get lost, i.e. there is no guarantee you will receive a response to your request. This is especially true for mobile devices that may loose their internet connection any time for various reasons: money is out, moving where there is no service, etc.

Sorry.

How you mitigate this depends on your application. Your strategy might include retrying the request, notifying the user and more.

Comment: Thank you! One quick question though. Is it a likely scenarion if I send two consecutive requests the second one reaches the server ahead of the first one?

Comment: Yes, the net-structure of the internet implies that two requests can take different routes through the network and thus possibly overtake each other. Again, there cannot be a _guarantee_ what happens to requests "in the internet".

Comment: Also see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213135